# Proofs involving sets for $\{9^n: n∈ℚ\}=\{3^n: n∈ℚ\}$.

Tags: proof-explanation

I need to prove that {9^n: n∈ℚ)={3^n: n∈ℚ).

So far I have proven {9^n: n∈ℚ}⊆{3^n: n∈ℚ}.

a∈{9^n: n∈ℚ}. Meaning for some a=9^n for some rational number.  Thus, a=9^n=3^2n, showing that a is a rational number for some power of 3. so a∈{9^n: n∈ℚ}.
Which also means
 {9^n: n∈ℚ}⊆{3^n: n∈ℚ}

But i don't know how to prove {3^n: n∈ℚ}⊆{9^n: n∈ℚ}.

So that I can say that {9^n: n∈ℚ)={3^n: n∈ℚ).

Comment: Can you relate 3 to 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\mathbb{Q}=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Q}$$

> So $9^\mathbb{Q}=9^{\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Q}}=(9^\frac{1}{2})^\mathbb{Q}=3^\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I know that for {3^n: n∈ℚ}⊆{9^n: n∈ℚ}. we need to somehow show that 9^1/2(n)= 3^n, but i'm not quite sure how.

Comment: @M.Maric Sorry, I don't know how to make the boxes alert "Spoiler" :(. This answer prove what you need, you just need to read every element as a set; i.e. for example the equality $9^\mathbb{Q}=3^\mathbb{Q}$ is the set equality $\{9^q:q\in\mathbb{Q}\}=\{3^q:q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, which is what you want!!

Comment: @M.Maric Try to prove every equality in the order they appear in my answer, I'll be glad to help if you get stuck. =)

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying. I actually did something similar for other problems involving proofs with modulo